# i need to get credentials of google calendar user without the user going into the consol?google.com website

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

hi can do the crud of google calendar in my own application on an mvc app .net 5. but i need to get the credentials of a user when he logs in so that i can store them in my own database. is there a way to skip the console.google.com part so that the user gets only needs to log in?

```
public ActionResult OauthRedirect()
        {
            var credentialsFile = "C:\\Users\\credentials.json";

            JObject credentials = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(credentialsFile));
            var client_id = credentials["client_id"];

            var redirectUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" +
                               "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events&" +
                               "access_type=offline&" +
                               "include_granted_scopes=true&" +
                               "response_type=code&" +
                               "state=hellothere&" +
                               "redirect_uri=https://localhost:44311/Reservation/Calendar&" +
                               "client_id=" + client_id;
            
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
```

i am doing it like this for the moment to get al credentials. i downloaded the credentials.json file from console.goole.com but i need it have it practical for the end user so that the end user only needs to login.

Comment: Your going to have to authorize each user.   Unfortunately currently the google apis .net client library is not compatible with the standards asp .net authorization.  So your not going to be able to do it at the time they login. And your going to have to code it all yourself manually.  You can follow [issue 2225](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2225) if you would like to encourage google to fix the issue.

Comment: so i need to make a documentation for the end user so that they can add via the console.google.com credentials and api key @DaImTo

Comment: you only need one client id via the google developer console, that is created by you the developer.   [Understanding oauth2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for the info i already got that but its more to know how to get the api key client id and  client secret without using the console.google.com

Comment: You cant. You the developer must go to console.google.com Create a project for your application, then define the credentials you will need for your app, in this case client id, client secrete and api key if you need one.   This is the developers responsibility and not something users of the application should be doing.  There is no way to do this programmatically it must be done manually by the developer of the app.

Comment: yes i understand but what happens when the user wants to login via goole on your app whatdo the pas to the developer then? or what does the the developer receives in let sya a methode in c# @DaImTo

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you understand the flow better https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: could we maybe do a call?

Comment: I offer a consulting service you can find my email in the about tab of my YouTube channel.

Comment: the problem is that each user on the app has a separated agenda thatneeds to be synct with the agenda on my app @DaImTo

Comment: Not sure why that's a problem it seems standard to me.   You need consent from the user to access their Google calendar data.     If your app has an internal calendar then our going to either have to create a google workspace account so you can use a service account.   Or you will need to authorize your calendar once and store the token so that you will be able to access it as needed.     None of this would require that your users create client ids, or api keys on google cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood what the Client credentials (client id, client secrete and api key) are used for.

When you want to create a new application, that will access Google apis.  You go to [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) you create a new project.  Within that project you would create the client credentials you need and under library denote what apis you will be using.

These are project / application based credentials they are used by your application request access of users. There is no limit to the number of users your application can request access of using these application credentials.

An api key will give your application access to public data.
The client id and client secrete will give your application the ability to request consent to access user data from any number of users.

When your application requests consent of a user to access their data

[image]

Assuming they consent and grant you access.  An access token and refresh token is returned to you

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

These tokens are user specific and linked to your client id.

For each user you authorize you will get a new access token and refresh token which your application can use to access the users data.

> but does every user of the app needs to give there api key and credentials to the developer?

No every user does not give your an api key and credentials. those are specific to your application and your application alone.  You create them.  You use them to request consent of the user.

Please watch this video it will explain how the oauth2 flow works [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)